# Application Banach Steinhaus: cannot see my mistake

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

I'm studying Banach Steinhaus theorem in Rudin's functional analysis (page 43-46). 
Theorem 2.9 says: If $X$,$Y$ are two topological vector spaces, $K$ is a compact convex set in $Y$, $\Gamma$ is a collection of continuous linear maps $X\to Y$ and the orbits $\Gamma(x)=\{\Lambda(x)|\Lambda \in \Gamma\}$ are boundend subsets of $Y$ for every $x\in K$.
Then there is a bounded set $B\subset Y$ such that $\Gamma(K)\subset B$.

I understand the proof of the theorem BUT:
$K$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, so by Baire's theorem is of second cathegory. By Banach Steinhaus theorem $\Gamma|_K$ is an equicontinuous collection of linear maps, thus (theorem 2.4)  $\Gamma|_K$ are equibounded. Finally since $K$ is bounded  $\Gamma|_K(K)=\Gamma (K)$ is a bounded subset of $Y$.

I presume there is something wrong with this argument since I didn't use the convexity of $K$.

Comment: Convexity does seem unnecessary, as you say. However, replacing $K$ by its convex hull does not change the hypothesis, so both statements (with or without convexity) are equivalent.

Comment: So do you think the argument is correct?

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply the Banach-Steinhaus Theorem, you need $K$ to be a topological vector space. You could consider the space spanned by $K$. Call it $Z$. Although the pointwise boundedness assumption still holds on $Z$, it might not be the case that $Z$ is nonmeagre. Although $K$ is nonmeagre *in itself*, it might be meagre as a subset of a larger topological space.

Exercise 8 of the same chapter of the same book provides an example of this: even though $K$ is compact, the space spanned by $K$ is infinite-dimensional. More precisely, it is the union of countably many finite-dimensional subspaces, so that (by exercise 1) it is meagre and Banach-Steinhaus does not apply.